# Passing dynamic class name to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div inside a `foreach` loop I'm using to display content in view

```
<div class="someclass" data-id="get_@item.GetYear">
    <p> text1 </p>
    <p> text2 </p>
<span class="otherClass embedIcon"></span>
</div>
```

I'm trying to target the id attribute using the

```
$(".embedIcon")
    .click(function () {
        html2canvas($(this).data('data-id'),{
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1);
                window.open(myImage);
            }
        });
    });
```

When I click the icon on which `embedIcon` class is applied to generates an image, I get an image of all divs in the iteration.

How can I get the image of a specific div when I click the icon within the div?

Comment: post full code.

Comment: it should be like this `html2canvas($(this).data('id')`

Comment: @Mahi I posted full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your id is on your parent div, not on the embedIcon, so you can use 2 options

```
var id = $(this).parent().data('id')
html2canvas(id, {
```

or

```
var id = $(this).closest('.someclass').data('id')
html2canvas(id, {
```

**Update:**

[html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html) accepts the element as first parameter, not the id, so you only need to pass the parent to your html2canvas call, you don't need the data-id. You can use `.parent()` or `.closest(".someclass")`

```
$(".embedIcon")
    .click(function () { 
        html2canvas($(this).parent(),{
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1);
                window.open(myImage);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: The second option does not achieve desired result.
I get this error `Uncaught TypeError: node.setAttribute is not a function(…)` when I try the first option

Comment: sorry I forgot the dot before the class name, updated

Comment: same error with both options?, can you do a console.log(id) before passing it to html2canvas?

Comment: I get actual value of `data-id` in log but error still show up in application.

Comment: @hello html2canvas accepts the element as first parameter, not the id, check the tested updated answer before.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using data() than it should be like:

```
$(this).data('id');
```

and if using attr() than it should be like:

```
$(this).attr('data-id');
```

Comment: I still get same behaviour as before. Check updated question and sample code.